# filter scandir and sort by date created

Tags: php

1. I need to get the files in a directory in an array.

   - Only files that end in .markdown
2. The files should be sorted by date created

Efficiency is not a *huge* deal, but I always like to make things as efficient as possible.  There will be multiple directories with up to a couple hundred files in each.

I know I use the `scandir` function to get the files into an array, but I'm not sure where to go from there.  I could throw it in a loop to check if the files end in `.markdown`, but is there some sort of regex I could pass in to the scan?

Thanks

Comment: http://fabien.potencier.org/article/43/find-your-files

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`glob()`](http://php.net/glob) to get an array of filenames then use [`usort()`](http://php.net/usort) and [`filectime()`](http://php.net/filectime) to order them by their creation dates:

```
$files = glob('*.markdown');
usort($files, function($file_1, $file_2)
{
    $file_1 = filectime($file_1);
    $file_2 = filectime($file_2);
    if($file_1 == $file_2)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return $file_1 < $file_2 ? 1 : -1;
});
```

For PHP versions lower than 5.3:

```
function sortByCreationTime($file_1, $file_2)
{
    $file_1 = filectime($file_1);
    $file_2 = filectime($file_2);
    if($file_1 == $file_2)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return $file_1 < $file_2 ? 1 : -1;
}

$files = glob('*.markdown');
usort($files, 'sortByCreationTime');
```

Comment: Wow! 5 years... 5 years and I didn't know that! Well, I didn't actually worked a lot with a filesystem in PHP, but it's kinda weak excuse for self. Thanks :)

Comment: Wow, awesome. Though I'm getting a syntax error `unexpected T_FUNCTION`

Comment: @Switz:  You need to be running at least PHP 5.3 for the above code to work.  I'll add a PHP 5.3 > capable version.

Comment: Enabling PHP 5.3 right now.  I'll let you know how it goes. -- Works perfectly! Thanks!

Comment: One thing. It should be `$file_1 < $file_2` so that the newest item is on top.

Comment: hm.. there's no creation time in Unix. ctime is the change time, says PHP documentation. I think ctime changes every time you modify the file, or you set new permissions, owner etc to it.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to get the file list is simply do

```
$files = glob('*.markdown');
```

glob() basically does the same kind of wildcard matching that occurs at a shell prompt.

Sorting by date will require you to look at each of those files with `stat()` and retrieve its mtime/ctime/atime values (which fileatime(), filemtime(), filectime() return directly, but still use stat() internally).